# Why am I getting a SQL Relation Error if I include certain parameters?

Tags: sql

When I query the following, I get results

```
select created_at, ready_at, completed_at, Date_trunc('day', created_at) as day_created
from tasks
```

But when I try to add count(day_created) to the end of the select query, EG

```
select created_at, ready_at, completed_at, Date_trunc('day', created_at) as day_created, count(day_created)
from tasks
```

I start getting "ERROR: relation "tasks" does not exist"

The query also works fine if I do not include the created_at, ready_at, completed_at columns.

Frustrating...

Comment: count() is an aggregate function, it generates a count of items *per group*, so you have to declare the set of columns which define a group using a GROUP BY clause

Comment: also, which database are you using?

Comment: Redshift database. Adding Group by (day_created) did not change the outcome though.

Comment: You want to count how many rows are in a group, so group over everything *except* the aggregating function. Nevertheless, you can't refer to an alias in the same select statement. You need a subquery to calculate `day_created`, in the outer query you can do the count, grouped by everything else

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you what you are expecting?

```
select 
    date_trunc('day', created_at) as day_created, 
    count(*)
from 
    tasks
group by
    date_trunc('day', created_at)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That does get some results, again if I try to add additional columns it stops getting results. Perhaps b/c of the explanation by honeybadger.

Comment: Yes, any column in the SELECT that is not an aggregate of the group must be included in the GROUP BY clause as defining the group

Comment: That said, you could use COUNT() as a window function instead of an aggregate function if that is what you really want instead